# Java Model Hibernate Mapping Issue

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

*Note: I have Used Spring Data Jpa for persistence.*

**Problem:**

I have two Models: **User** and **Badge**

I have a List of Badges owned By a User as data member in **User** class.
I also have User as data member in **Badge** class (i.e. The creator of the badge)

I want to make relationship between user and List of badges data member.
relationship is of type OneToMany (i.e. One User will going to have Many Badges) and vice versa also.

I want it to work in this way,
in code ,

When I save badge object with issuer (aka user) set to a particular user object , then need not to add it (the badge) into user's List of badges Owned by it.

I have tried to create the relationship but it returns an empty list of User Owned Badge in REST API response.

**Badge Model**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "badges")
public class Badge {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "badge_id")
    private int mId;
    @Column(name = "badge_name" , nullable = false , unique = true)
    private String mName;
    @Column(name = "badge_description")
    private String mDescription;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "badge_logo" , nullable = false)
    private String mLogo;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "issuer_id")
    private User mIssuer;
}
```

**User Model**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long mId;
    @Column(name = "username" , nullable = false , unique = true)
    private String mUserName;
    @Column(name = "fullname",nullable = false)
    private String mFullName;
    @Column(name = "salt")
    private String mSalt;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mIssuer",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Badge> mOwnedBadges;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "received_badges_id")
    private List<Badge> mReceivedBadges;
}
```

**CommandLineRunner**

```
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.Badge;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.User;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Services.Intefaces.BadgeSerivce;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Services.Intefaces.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Component
public class StartupExecutor implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private BadgeSerivce mBadgeSerivce;
    @Autowired
    private UserService mUserService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //TODO:: issuer cannot issue badge to itself
        final User user1 = new User();
        user1.setFullName("User1 FullName");
        user1.setSalt("salt1");
        user1.setUserName("User1 UserName");
        mUserService.save(user1);

        final User user2 = new User();
        user2.setFullName("User2 FullName");
        user2.setSalt("salt2");
        user2.setUserName("User2 UserName");
        mUserService.save(user2);


        Badge badge1 = new Badge();
        badge1.setDescription("Desc1");
        badge1.setLogo("Logo1");
        badge1.setName("Badge1");
        badge1.setIssuer(user1);
        mBadgeSerivce.save(badge1);

        Badge badge2 = new Badge();
        badge2.setDescription("Desc2");
        badge2.setLogo("Logo2");
        badge2.setName("Badge2");
        badge2.setIssuer(user2);
        mBadgeSerivce.save(badge2);

        Badge badge3 = new Badge();
        badge3.setDescription("Desc3");
        badge3.setLogo("Logo3");
        badge3.setName("Badge3");
        badge3.setIssuer(user1);
        mBadgeSerivce.save(badge3);


        user1.setReceivedBadges(Arrays.asList(badge2));

        user2.setReceivedBadges(Arrays.asList(badge1,badge3));
    }
}
```

*Note: It doesn't save user Received Badges list also , if you can figure that out too , then I will really be thankful to you.*

**BadgeRepo**

```
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.Badge;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BadgeRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Badge,Long> {
}
```

**UserRepo**

```
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User,Long> {
}
```

**BadgeServiceImpl**

```
package com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Services.Implentations;

import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Repository.BadgeRepo;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.Badge;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Services.Intefaces.BadgeSerivce;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class BadgeServiceImpl implements BadgeSerivce {
    @Autowired
    private BadgeRepo mBadgeRepo;
    @Override
    public List<Badge> getAllBadges(int pageNumber , int sizeOfPage) {
        if (sizeOfPage > 20) {
            sizeOfPage = 20;
        }
        final Page<Badge> allPages = mBadgeRepo.findAll(PageRequest.of(pageNumber,
                sizeOfPage));
        if (allPages.getTotalElements() > 0) {
            return allPages.toList();
        } else{
            return new ArrayList<Badge>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Badge badge) {
        mBadgeRepo.save(badge);
    }
}
```

**UserServiceImpl**

```
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.Badge;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Models.User;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Repository.UserRepo;
import com.badging.spinnerbadger.SpinnerBadger.Services.Intefaces.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo mUserRepo;
    @Override
    public void save(User user) {
        mUserRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Badge> getUsersReceivedBadgeList(long userId) {
        final Optional<User> byId = mUserRepo.findById(userId);
        return byId.orElse(new User()).getReceivedBadges();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Badge> getUserOwnedBadgeList(long userId) {
        final Optional<User> byId = mUserRepo.findById(userId);
        return byId.orElse(new User()).getReceivedBadges();
    }
}
```

**Generated SQL** by Hibernate -> 1st for User model and 2nd  for Badge Model

```
Hibernate: insert into users (fullname, salt, username, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: insert into badges (badge_description, issuer_id, badge_logo, badge_name, badge_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: are you flushing your changes after `commit`?

Comment: I feel there are a couple of things that are missing that would help answering this. First, it is unclear how BadgeService and UserServiced are implemented. In my test application, I made them interfaces that extend JpaRepository. Second, I do not follow how mReceivedBadges is mapped. Looking at it, I feel there should be another table and entity. In my sample application. I could not get this part to run as-is and left it out. With both of those changes, I was able to create the data in this function and then retrieve a User with owned badges in a REST endpoint.

Comment: @Vishrant No i am not flushing or even commiting, i am using JpaRepository's save method() to persist entity.

Comment: @darrendanvers BadgeService and UserService are abstarcting the operations of BadgeRepo(inteface) and UserRepo(inteface) respectively. Both Repo interface extends JpaRepository. **I have Added the code into the post please refer there**.

Comment: @darrendanvers For the second point , i also know that there are some issues with the relationship , i think i will need to add two seperate entity , one should be **DisplayableBadge** and **RecievableBadge** , like in former there must be User object whoowns the object and in latter there must be a User object who is the Reciever of the badge and there must be a Owner(aka one who have created it) User object. Am i Thinking right? , although my first priority is to get the owner list fetched first.

Comment: Looking at the implementations of those services, I'm wondering if you are even finding the user when searching by ID. If the user is not found, you would return an empty list. I would validate that first. For the mapping, I feel you just need one. new entity that contains a user and a badge to hold the badges a user has received. mReceivedBadges would be a list of these entities.

Comment: `hibernate.show_sql=true` add this and check what's happening at the hibernate level, as Jens suggested in the answer section check if this can be part of a `Transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things that might go wrong here.

1. You don't seem to have transactions specified. Add `@Transactional` to those beans or methods that should participate in a transaction. At the very least that should include everything that modifies (eventually) the database, i.e. any statement modifying a managed entity, including the one that loads it from the database and `save` statements. I'm expecting this to be the actual cause of the problem you are seeing.
2. You don't seem to have code in place that synchronises the both sides of a bidirectional relationship. So, when you call
   `badge1.setIssuer(user1)`,
   `user1` does not get updated, so if you call `user1.getOwnedBadges()`
   it will still return the unchanged (empty) value.

   I doubt it is a problem in this case, but it will result in the
   relationship looking different within a single transaction,
   depending from which side you are looking at it. And changes to the
   non-owning side (`User` in your case) will not get persisted. So this should be fixed
   anyways. See also https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/
3. When saving an entity, you should use the instance returned by the `save` method, not the one passed to `save` as an argument. Often they are the same but when they aren't modifying the one passed to `save` might not result in the state persisted to the database.

If these things are fixed and problems persist I recommend the following to gather more information about what is going on:

1. Activate [logging of SQL statements including parameters](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) in order to see what is actually persisted (and when).
2. Create a JUnit test testing your services. This makes it much clearer what is actually executed and allows to create variants to compare.

Comment: Firstly i appreciate the time and energy you are devoting to answer to my problem. Now i Will talk about third point first , save method of JpaRepository doesn't return saved entity so its not possible (although i can create a custom method which save an entity and query it though some unique identifier). Now i will talk about 2nd point of yours , i am not able to understand which type of code synchronizing you are talking about , i have defined jpa annotation well (have seen few tutorials they have done the same and their mapping works) and need not to synchronize.

Comment: `save` return an instance. It's inherited from `CrudRepository` https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-

Comment: Now i will talk about your first point , You mean that i should add @Transactional to save method's in service implementation classes,right?  **I have added SQL generated by hibernate for insertion of entities into database , at the end of my post refer there.**

Comment: I updated the answer to clarify the point about synchronisation.

Comment: `@Transactional` should be added to `save` methods in the service implementation, but also (and in this case more importantly to `StartupExecutor.run`

Comment: Isn't synchronization hibernate's headache ? I have defined relationship right, although i can say that look into generated sql command it will aid a lot. I have added @Transactional annotation at every save method and also to StartupExecutor's run() method too.

Comment: JPA doesn't do synchronisation, which many assume it does. Hibernate added a way to let it handle this, but I'm not sure in which version and what one has to do to enable it.

Comment: As JPA is specification it won't do anything , it is the implimentor which will provide the synchronization , i have worked with hibernate a little bit , it works in the way i am thinking , but this time i don't know why it isn't happening , although i appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes JPA is only the specification, but this specification does not mandate synchronisation. You probably know the article already, but for others this article might be of interest:
https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/